# Jquery sortable not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

```
<div id="chapters">

{% for chapter in chapters %}
    <div id="chapter-{{ forloop.counter }}">
        <legend>Chapter{{ forloop.counter }}</legend>
        <label for="id_subtitle">Subtitle:</label>
        <input id="id_subtitle" maxlength="255" name="subtitle" type="text" value="{{chapter.subtitle}} ">
        <label for="id_content">Content:</label>
        <input id="id_content" maxlength="255" name="content" type="text" value="{{chapter.content}} ">
        <label for="id_upload">File:</label>
        <a href="/media/{{chapter.upload}}">view</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url "chapters-edit" pk=chapter.pk %}">Edit chapter</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
$(function() {
$('[id^="chapter-"]').draggable({
  // appendTo: "body",
  // helper: "clone"
});
$("#chapters").droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
  }

}).sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    helper:'clone',
    stop: function(e, ui) {
    console.log($('#sortable').sortable('toArray'));
    }
 });
```

});

I can drag chapters, but they dont sort... and i can drop them anywhere on page which also sholudnt be happening. What am i doing wrong? TY

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any error messages? Have you tried debugging? Where did you get the code from? These are all questions that help us answer your question and help you.

Comment: i got it from source code from jquery dropable example of cart shopping.. when i remove draggable and droppable, it's seems to be kinda working.. but it only sorts the title and not whole form.. no errors..

Comment: So, removing draggable and droppable actually made it work.. why is that? I was following this example: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart 
How can i make that chapters changes number once they are rearranged? And how can I save new order so that when i reload the page i got the new order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `draggable()` and `droppable()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#chapters").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    helper: 'clone',
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log($('#sortable').sortable('toArray'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This did the trick.. Can you explain why it didnt work in first place?  I was following this example: jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart How can i make that chapters changes number once they are rearranged? And how can I save new order so that when i reload the page i got the new order?

Comment: btw I'm working in Django. console.log($('#chapters').sortable('toArray')); prints me the new order, how can i save that order?

Comment: @ssapp Your code messed up sortable because sortable items are made draggable and droppable internally. Explicitly initializing them as such probably  mess things up. Regarding other things, do one thing at a time, ask 1 question per post.